# PHP Unknown sender

Tags: php, html, forms, web

Hello I am fairly new to PHP and do not know a lot at the moment. I have modified a contact form an have come into some problems regarding the mail going straight to junk.

I assume this is for the reason that (unknown sender) keeps displaying in the email header. I would appreciate it if someone could help me correct this. The following is the code that I have implemented into the website:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Wirral PT Enquiry'; 
$to = 'joebloggs@hotmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Wirral PT Enquiry';
$human = $_POST['human'];
$headers = "enquiry@wirralpt.co.uk";
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
        if ($human == '2') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
            } else { 
                echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
            } 
        } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
            echo '<p> 1+1=2!! </p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>You need to fill everything!!</p>';
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Depending on the SMTP server, the `From: ` header should contain an email, eg: `From: Wirral PT Enquiry <something@somewhere.com>`. You should at least try `From: something@somewhere.com` and see if the SMTP server isn't overwriting your `From: ` header somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$from = 'From: Wirral PT Enquiry';`  should contain the 'from' email address, not just the name:

```
 $from = 'From: Wirral PT Enquiry <enquiry@wirralpt.co.uk>';
```

Try that?

Comment: I think the email address got swallowed by the editor thinking it was a tag

Comment: fixed :) but the answer below is more complete

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
$headers = "Reply To :enquiry@wirralpt.co.uk";
```

Might work for you

also,

```
$headers = "From :enquiry@wirralpt.co.uk";
```

try both of these with you relevant email IDs

Comment: The problem is that headers isn't being used - Update $from and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Change your headers to this:

```
$headers = 'From: enquiry@wirralpt.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: enquiry@wirralpt.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

and your mail should look this this:

```
mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)
```

Answer (score -2):

This error can also be caused if while using SMTP settings for PhpMailer,     $mail->IsSMTP(); is missed